# What is the name of following G based chord?

Tags: chords, acoustic-guitar, chord-theory, chord-inversions

What is the name of following chord starting at the bottom E string of a guitar: E2, A2, G4, B3? It is found at second marker 0:36 of the following youtube video if you want to see it being played.

Answer (score 1):

It's a G6 chord: `3 x 2 4 3 x` (from low E to high e, counted from the capo); due to the capo it sounds like an Ab6 chord. If you like you could just replace it by a standard G chord.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake for making the assumption that the OP's transcription of the chord was correct. Since they said the chord starts on E2 (so F#-B-D-B-D-E), I determined Bm. Seeing that the chord starts on E3 (so G-B-D-B-D-E), your answer is definitely correct. I should have watched the clip =)